# How do I get my Minecraft Pocket Edition password if I have forgotten it?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I don't know what I need to do to find my password since I have forgotten it.

When I try to sign in, it tells me that there is an error with my password and "this account is already registered".

What do I have to do to be able to sign in again?

Answer (score -1):

You have to change your gamer tag and then register again.

Comment: You probably shouldn't announce your gamertag so freely